# Button is not take its properties?

Tags: android

I am developing an UI(Home screen) just like this screen 
    given in this link
    http://www.flickr.com/photos/78431491@N07/7023063473/

-all information are comming from xml which is available on server means 
    1- number of button on screen
    2- size, background images of screen and buttons,text on button each and everythings coming from
       server 
    so we can't use xml for creating layout.I have been comleted tabbar and when I am creating buttons that is not taking any properties code used by me is as-

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.correlation.edumationui:drawable/" + img, null, null);
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeScreen.class);//HomeScreen.class);
        Bundle objbundle = new Bundle();
        objbundle.putSerializable("screen", mscreen);
        intent.putExtras(objbundle);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("title").setIndicator(title,getResources().getDrawable(id))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

for creating button i am using this code--in homescreen Activity( HomeScreen.class)

```
LinearLayout buttonsView = new LinearLayout(this);
    buttonsView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int r = 0; r < 6; ++r)
    {
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setText("A");
     btn.setHeight(30);
     btn.setWidth(224);
     btn.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); // Verbose!
     lp.weight = 1.0f; // This is critical. Doesn't work without it.
     buttonsView.addView(btn, lp);
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    setContentView(buttonsView, lp);
```

give me your valuable help....

Comment: Which properties are not able to get, can give more details?

Comment: not Take setHeght(),and setWidth() also not take padding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); // Verbose!
 lp.weight = 1.0f; // This is critical. Doesn't work without it.
 buttonsView.addView(btn, lp);
```

Use

```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 224); // Verbose!
   lp.weight = 1.0f; // This is critical. Doesn't work without it.
   buttonsView.addView(btn,lp);
```

to reflect the width and height of buttons in layout parameters.

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(110,0); // Verbose!
         btn.setText("TEST123");
         btn.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
         lp.weight = 1.0f; // This is critical. Doesn't work without it.
         buttonsView.addView(btn,lp);

Comment: i am use above code but sir it not work please help meI have been use new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(110,0);//(50,50)but no any effect

Comment: for the height to reflect, remove lp.weight = 1.0. This line means that its height will be equal to the parent linear layout's height.

Comment: thanks sir now it is working? May you give your email address I want to make contact with you?

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutParameters to set width, height and margins on button.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Height, Width and Padding using setLayoutParams as:

```
Button btn = new Button (this);
LayoutParams  params = Prams // Set Params Which you want to set for your view.
btn.setLayoutPrams(params);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Set Height and width programmatically, you have use set layoutparams like below.

```
LinearLayout ly = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.verify);
 Button buyButton = new Button(this);
        buyButton.setText("button");
        buyButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,
        50));
        buyButton.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        ly.addView(buyButton);
```